# Video streaming on Android application with Gstreamer

Tags: android, http, streaming, gstreamer, ip-camera

I am using the modified tutorial 3 (android*1) for do streaming from other phone with the android aplication "IP Webcam"*2. 
the program work but i have a problem when i call nativePlay() the application takes a long time to load the video and when when the video load then the video is accelerated until it appears in real time after a few seconds / minutes depending on the resolution of the image. 
I guess since we launched the function until the video is displayed in the application are saving the video and so appears accelerated. I read the code but can not find where is this buffer to remove and does not take so long to display the video 
I hope I may be able to help.

*1(http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+3%3A+Video)

Code:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwB3O9F5yEPMazNyUy1OYlU1TW8&usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I forgot upload the code https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwB3O9F5yEPMazNyUy1OYlU1TW8&usp=sharing

Comment: please add the code in the question.